# R - Issue coupling DeSolve ODE with purrr:map

Tags: r, purrr, desolve

I'm trying to automate my code, which requires solving ODE, over the changes of different parameters.

I have a nested data frame, with 2 columns:

- PP, which is my "main" variable
- data, which gathers 14 variables computed from the PP value.

This `test_df_nested`dataframe looks like:

```
PP  | data 
0.0 | 14 variables
0.1 | 14 variables
0.2 | 14 variables
```

When unnesting the `data` column, I get:

```
PP  | u_croiss | kUpeak | kUstable | w_0 |... 
0.0 | 30000    | 560000 | 480000   | 300 |...
0.1 | 42000    | 588000 | 504000   | 420 |...
0.2 | 54000    | 616000 | 528000   | 540 |...
```

I then want to apply an ODE function to give me the evolution of 2 variables (U and V) over time on every row of my nested data frame. So, here, I'm trying to use the `ode`function from the `deSolve`package, and make it run over several sets of parameters using `map`function from the `purrr`package.

As described in the help of the `ode` function, I defined my `yini` with 2 initial values, defined the `times` and the list of parameters `pars`.

I then apply the `ode` function using these variables and stock the result in a `out` object.

Every step here is embedded in a custom function named `make_ODE`, that returns `out`.

To run this custom function over all sets of parameters that I have in my nested df, I use the `map` function as such:

```
test <- test_df_nested %>% 
  mutate(outputs = map2(PP,data, ~make_ODE(.x, .y)))
```

The `make_ODE` function looks like:

```
make_ODE <- function(PP,data){

  Unnested_df <- test_df_nested %>% 
    unnest(data)
  
  yini  <- c(V = 1)
  # Set the initial value of V = 1
  
  times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)
  
  
  # PARS should be one value at a time
  parms  <- c(
    # v_croiss = Unnested_df$u_croiss,
    # v_croiss = c(3000,4000,5000) #Where the problem occurs
    k_V = 100)
  # k_U = kVlow,
  # u_croiss = 2)
  
  actual_ode <- function(yini, times, parms){
    out   <- ode(y = yini,
                 times,
                 equa_diff_sp_test_nest,
                 parms,
                 method = "rk4") %>% 
      as_tibble()
    
    return(out)
    
  }
  
  res <-actual_ode(yini, times, parms)
  return(res)
  
}
```

Where `equa_diff_sp_test_nest` is a function defined with:

```
equa_diff_sp_test_nest <- function(t,y,parms){
  
  V  <- y[1]

  
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {
    

    dVdt <- v_croiss * V * (1 - V/k_V)
    

        return(list(c(dVdt)))
  })
}
```

It works for a 1 row `test_df_nested`. But for more rows, the code generates an error, telling me that the output of the `ode` function has more elements than the initial vector `y`. Indeed, while `y` has 2 elements, the outputs have `2*nrows(test_df_nested)`.

I imagine the error comes from my custom function, but I can't understand where.

Edit: I think one of the problem might come from the fact that the `parms` vector does not change values according to the row of the nested df. For instance, in the example, there is 3 differents values of the `u_croiss` parameter, each should be used for solving the ODE, at each value of `PP`.

Another issue is that I have, on one hand, `PP`dependant parameters, that are stored in a nested df, upon which I apply the `map` function. On the other hand, I have `time` dependant parameters which should be computed through the `ODE` but using parameters from the nested df.

Actually, my question would be: how can I iterate a customed function with map, where parameters of the custom function vary with time.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's the output of the `dput(test_df_nested)`:

```
structure(list(PP = c(0, 0.1, 0.2), data = list(structure(list(
    u_croiss = 30000, kUpeak = 560000, kUstable = 480000, w_0 = 300, 
    kWpeak = 9700, kWstable = 4500, k_m = 0.84, k_c = 4.74, chi_M = 9.31204630137287e-09, 
    chi_C = 2.91010985906386e-08, t_low = 105, t_kpeak = 155, 
    t_kstable = 255), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(u_croiss = 42000, kUpeak = 588000, 
    kUstable = 504000, w_0 = 420, kWpeak = 10185, kWstable = 4725, 
    k_m = 0.956, k_c = 5.409, chi_M = 9.24967155645443e-09, chi_C = 2.90483478901307e-08, 
    t_low = 105, t_kpeak = 152.5, t_kstable = 252.5), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    u_croiss = 54000, kUpeak = 616000, kUstable = 528000, w_0 = 540, 
    kWpeak = 10670, kWstable = 4950, k_m = 1.072, k_c = 6.078, 
    chi_M = 9.19322958436019e-09, chi_C = 2.90004488568525e-08, 
    t_low = 105, t_kpeak = 150, t_kstable = 250), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(
    PP = c(0, 0.1, 0.2), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi Rachel! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: In my experience questions with code AND data get solved a LOT faster than ones without, or ones with just one of the two. If you could include your data (`dput(test_df_nested)`), that'd be great! Thanks :-)

Comment: Hey @Mark! Thanks for the welcoming! I edited the post, hoping it's enough info. 
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm having trouble with your code since I don't know what `kVlow` or `equa_diff_sp_test_nest` are. Can you make a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: hi @pgcudahy, I edited my question following your request. `kVlow` is a parameter defined in another script, loaded using `source` function. `equa_diff_sp_test_nest` is the function used to determine the evolution the growth rate of my parameter `dVdt`, solved using ODE. 

Tell me if it's still unclear. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Rachel, just a quick note: a [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837926/3677576) shows a way how to solve your problem with a simpler and more streamlined pipeline that avoids nested lists.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Thanks a lot for letting me know, I'll look into that! (After running the code from your more recent post, I'm amazed by how simple the whole process is now). Thanks again for your interest for my question and the answer provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, things like this can be made much easier, without the need of nested data frames, nested function definitions and `map2`. I would also recommend to simplify data and code further, to make it a minimal reproducible "toy"-example. Nevertheless, a main issue was the unnesting step in the `make_ode` function that re-uses the global `test_df_nested` data frame instead of the local `data` variable.

So instead of:

```r
Unnested_df <- test_df_nested %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

consider to use:

```r
Unnested_df <-  unnest(data, cols=c())
```

The resulting code can then look like:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("purrr")
library("deSolve")

## data omitted for compactness
# test_df_nested <- structure(list(PP = c(0, 0.1, 0.2), data = .....

make_ODE <- function(PP, data){
  
  Unnested_df <-  unnest(data, cols=c())
  
  yini  <- c(V = 1)
  times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)
  
  # PARS should be one value at a time
  parms  <- c(
    v_croiss = Unnested_df$u_croiss,
    k_V = 100)

  actual_ode <- function(yini, times, parms){
    out   <- ode(y = yini,
                 times,
                 equa_diff_sp_test_nest,
                 parms,
                 method = "rk4") %>% 
      as_tibble()
    return(out)
  }
  res <- actual_ode(yini, times, parms)
  return(res)
  
}

equa_diff_sp_test_nest <- function(t, y, parms){
  V  <- y[1]
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {
    dVdt <- v_croiss * V * (1 - V/k_V)
    return(list(c(dVdt)))
  })
}

test <- test_df_nested %>% 
  mutate(outputs = map2(PP, data, ~make_ODE(.x, .y)))
```

### Final Remarks

- The output data don't make sense yet, but I assume this should work with the full model and sensful parameters.
- Instead of using nested lists and `map2` the same can be done much easier with flat (unnested) dataframes and an `apply`-function.
- Instead of `rk4` I would recommend to use an odepack solver.

Package **deSolve** contains two families of solvers, (1) "industry-strength" solvers from the [Fortran ODEPACK library](https://netlib.org/odepack/), and (2) solvers from the classical Runge-Kutta family, implemented in C.

Except for special cases, ODEPACK solvers (e.g. `lsoda` or `vode`) should be preferred. They are faster and numerically more stable. All ODEPACK solvers use an automatic integration step size while the RK family contains algorithms with automatic (e.g. `ode45`) or fixed step size  (e.g. `rk4`). The classical `rk4` is easy to implement and sometimes useful for teaching and debugging, but can be numerically unstable and has "practically unknown" precision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It's now working the way I wanted.

I should take a look into the `apply` function family, but I thought the `map` and nested dataframe were preferable in this case. Also, I used the `rk4` method because once again, I learned to do it this way. But I don't understand your remark, since the `rk4` is one of the method provided by an odepack solver (in this case, `deSolve`)?